# TableView with different cell values in javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview, cell

In the following code there are 4 columns. In "Particular Value" column different types of data can be added like string, integer, date, etc. But I want to add a button in same column next to value entered in that cell, only if that value is string.

something like this:

### First name| Last Name| Age| Particular value

James | Smith | 10  | 10

Jacob | Wisly | 20  | abc (button)

Anna  | Samaul | 15  | 45.5

How to do add button in same column only for particular cell i.e containing string value?

```
package application;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Main extends Application {

    private final TableView<Person<?>> tableView = new TableView<>();

    private Person<Integer> person1 = new Person<>("Jacob", "Smith", 28, 4);
    private Person<Integer> person2 = new Person<>("Isabella", "Johnson", 19, 5);
    private Person<String> person3 = new Person<>("Bob", "The Sponge", 13, "Say Hi!");
    private Person<LocalDateTime> person4 = new Person<>("Time", "Is Money", 45, LocalDateTime.now());
    private Person<Double> person5 = new Person<>("John", "Doe", 32, 457.89);

    private final ObservableList<Person<?>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(person1, person2, person3, person4,
            person5);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableColumn<Person<?>, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Person<?>, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

        TableColumn<Person<?>, Integer> ageCol = new TableColumn<>("Age");
        ageCol.setMinWidth(50);
        ageCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("age"));

        TableColumn<Person<?>, ?> particularValueCol = new TableColumn<>("Particular Value");
        particularValueCol.setMinWidth(200);
        particularValueCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("particularValue"));

        tableView.setItems(data);

        // Type safety: A generic array of Table... is created for a varargs
        // parameter
        // -> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") to start method!
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, ageCol, particularValueCol);

        // Output in console the selected table view's cell value/class to check
        // that the data type is correct.
        SystemOutTableViewSelectedCell.set(tableView);

        // To check that table view is correctly refreshed on data changed..
        final Button agePlusOneButton = new Button("Age +1");
        agePlusOneButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            Person<?> person = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            try {
                person.setAge(person.getAge() + 1);
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                //
            }
        });

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(tableView, agePlusOneButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        primaryStage.setWidth(600);
        primaryStage.setHeight(750);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class Person<T> {

        private final StringProperty firstName;
        private final StringProperty lastName;
        private final IntegerProperty age;
        private final ObjectProperty<T> particularValue;

        private Person(String firstName, String lastName, Integer age, T particularValue) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
            this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
            this.particularValue = new SimpleObjectProperty<T>(particularValue);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public Integer getAge() {
            return age.get();
        }

        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age.set(age);
        }

        public IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
            return age;
        }

        public T getParticularValue() {
            return particularValue.get();
        }

        public void setParticularValue(T particularValue) {
            this.particularValue.set(particularValue);
        }

        public ObjectProperty<T> particularValueProperty() {
            return particularValue;
        }
    }

    public static final class SystemOutTableViewSelectedCell {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        public static void set(TableView tableView) {

            tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

            ObservableList selectedCells = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();

            selectedCells.addListener(new ListChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Change c) {
                    TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
                    Object val = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(tablePosition.getRow());
                    System.out.println("Selected Cell (Row: " + tablePosition.getRow() + " / Col: "
                            + tablePosition.getColumn() + ") Value: " + val + " / " + val.getClass());
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
TableColumn<Person<?>, Object> particularValueCol = new TableColumn<>("Particular Value");
particularValueCol.setMinWidth(200);
particularValueCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("particularValue"));

particularValueCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<Person<?>, Object>() {
    private Button button = new Button("A button");

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.toString());
            if (item instanceof String) {
                setGraphic(button);
            } else {
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: but this adds button in all the cells of that column.. can I add button only to specific cells of that column?

Comment: @Pooja No it doesn't. It only adds buttons in cells which are displaying a `String` in that column.

Comment: @Pooja You should at least have the basic politeness to try the code when someone tries to help you, instead of instantly dismissing it.

Comment: nit-picking: the resetting content condition should include a null item - there are odd corner cases not entirely in the hands of the application coder :)